# Pandas- from duplicate rows, keeping rows without null values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df= pd.DataFrame ({'id': [1,1,2,3,3, 4], 'test': ['a', np.nan, 'b','w', 'd', np.nan]})
```

as you see the "id" column has some duplicate values with different values for the "test" column. From duplicate rows, I want only keep rows without null values. if a duplicate rows does not have any null values, I want to keep it.

The output should be like this:

```
   id   value
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   w
3   3   d
4   4   NaN
```

I tried this, but it does not work because it removes the duplicate rows where the id = 3.

```
df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False, sort=False)['value'].first()
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sample data:

```
dup_id = df['id'].duplicated(keep=False)
df[~(dup_id & df.test.isna())]
```

gives what you want:

```
   id test
0   1    a
2   2    b
3   3    w
4   3    d
5   4  NaN
```